# random variable and probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory

consider a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,1]$

When I combinded that to $P_X=P(X^{-1}(A))$ then $P_X: \mathcal{P}(X(\Omega)) \rightarrow [0,1]$

Why does this make any sense? For each $B \subset \mathbb{R} $ is$X^{-1}(B)$ in $\Omega$ and not in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: $P_X$ is a measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$, not on the power set of $X(\Omega)$.

Comment: Ok...you mean$\mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,1]. But $ X^{-1} \subset \Omega $ and not in the Borel sigma algebra A. Why is that?

Comment: If $A$ is a Borel set then $X^{-1}(A)$ belongs the give sigma algebra on $\Omega$ by definition of a random variable. Hence $P(X^{-1}(A)$ makes sense.

Comment: I do not understand that. X is defined on $\Omega$ . Is that wrong?

Comment: $X^{-1}(B)$ is in $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ not in $\Omega$.

Comment: I see: Then $ X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ But for each $B \subset \mathbb{R}  $ there could be many different $\omega_j, w_k$ that fulfil $X(w_j)=X(w_k)=B$

Comment: So you have to pick a set containing these $\omega_j$

Comment: You are probably mistaking the notation. $X$ is not assumed to have an inverse. $X^{-1}(B)$ is defined as $\{\omega: X(\omega) \in B\}$.

Comment: Yes I think I assumed that in this way. Thank you for your help:) I appreciate it:)